# phpunit returns always "The System can not find the path specified"

Tags: xampp, phpunit

i'm trying to run tests but i always get a "Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden." (The system can not find the path specified.)

i already updated to latest version and changed back, tested with Verion 3.7 and 5.3 but everytime time same error.

My works system is a Windows 10 machine with xampp on Windows 10.

Any idea?

Here you can see the behaviour: http://screencast.com/t/mhh70zVxlf5

Comment: Without a code example we can't have any ideas except "you're not including all paths" or your setup has problems. You should really try Vagrant unless the production servers are Windows

Comment: it has to be with the setup. cause it doesn't matter which test i wanna run, it always has the same output. unfortunatly, vagrant is not option for that. it has to be run on windows, that should be possible i guess

Comment: then check your xampp setup, probably something wrong with he paths or the CLI config

Comment: yeah but phpunit is installed an i'm able to run it. don't know what i've made wrong: http://screencast.com/t/mhh70zVxlf5